# Changing bloodhound icons

Tags: javascript, bloodhound

I try to change the icons of bloodhound
i edited the file index.js with the following content:

```
global.appStore = {
dagre: false,
startNode: null,
endNode: null,
highlightedEdges: [],
spotlightData: {},
queryStack: [],
currentTooltip: null,
highResPalette: {
     imageScheme: {
'User': {
  url: './img1.png',
  scale: 1.3,
  clip: 0.85
},
},
....
.....
highResStyle: {
    nodes: {
        label: {
            by: 'label'
        },
        size: {
            by: 'degree',
            bins: 5,
            min: 10,
            max: 20
        },
        icon: {
            by: 'type',
            scheme: 'imageScheme'
        }
    },
    edges: {
        type : {
            by : 'type',
            scheme: 'edgeScheme'
        }
    }
},
```

but i am getting red question mark in black circle, t doesn`t work when i put url from internet site.

what to do?